# SOAP action error when using soapClient

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

i am getting this error when trying to make a soap call.

```
The SOAP action specified on the message, '', does not match the HTTP SOAP Action.
```

When i call  `$service->SearchTouristItems($sti);` (this function is further below) i get the above error and i have no idea why.

The below is the code i am using.

// i used http://www.urdalen.no/wsdl2php/ to create TCS2Service which extends SoapClient

```
$service = new TCS2Service() ;

$sd = new ServiceDescriptor;
$sd->UniqueIdentifier = 'xxxxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx';

$stic = new SearchTouristItemCriteria;
$stic->SearchString = array ('dublin') ;    

$sti = new SearchTouristItems;

$sti->searchTouristItemCriteria = $sd;
$sti->serviceDescriptor = $stic;

$result = $service->SearchTouristItems($sti);

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($result);
    echo "</pre>";



SearchTouristItems looks like this  
  /**
   *  
   *
   * @param SearchTouristItems $parameters
   * @return SearchTouristItemsResponse
   */
  public function SearchTouristItems(SearchTouristItems $parameters) {
    return $this->__soapCall('SearchTouristItems', array($parameters),       array(
            'uri' => 'http://tempuri.org/',
            'soapaction' => ''
           )
      );
  }
```

this is the initilization of the client

```
public function TCS2Service($wsdl = "http://www.example.com/services/TCS2Service.svc", $options = array( 'soap_version'  => SOAP_1_2, 
          'exceptions'    => true, 
          'trace'         => 1, 
          'cache_wsdl'    => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,)) {
  foreach(self::$classmap as $key => $value) {
    if(!isset($options['classmap'][$key])) {
      $options['classmap'][$key] = $value;
    }
  }
  parent::__construct($wsdl, $options);
}
```

Comment: your instance of `SoapClient` looks to be in wsdl-mode... why, then, are you using `__soapCall`? that pseudo-magic-method is mainly there for calls in non-wsdl mode. If you pass a wsdl, the client generates the methods _for you_.

Comment: the SoapClient was generated by wsdl2php and thus this method was also generated by wsdl2php.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure though but what is the value of `'soapaction' => ''` in your code is replaced with the provided parameter. I do not have that experience calling web services with PHP so just gave it a thought.

Answer (score 0):

I think your ws-addressing is not turned on. Please turn on the ws- 
addressing and check again.

Comment: How do i turn on ws-addressing

Comment: Kindly go through with this link http://www.dimuthu.org/blog/2008/11/26/5-facts-about-ws-addressing-action-in-wsfphp/

Answer (score 0):

What I would do :

- check if the SOAP action is well defined in the WSDL: look for `address location="`
- try another WSDL to php converter
- send the WSDL url so I can try it by my side